# Easiest way to add http header to Request in NGINX

Tags: nginx

Just need to add HTTP header to request without changing url hostname and port, but as going from documentation `add_header` works only for responses and `proxy_set_header` only works with `proxy_pass`

What directive can I use to do next:

```
server {
    listen 19123;
    server_name remote.server.com;

    location / {
        <command-to-set-request-header???>  Proxy-Remote-User  ValidUserName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Struggling with same issue, did you find any solution?